# LDAP: unable to enter DIT LDIF: LDAP_NO_SUCH_OBJECT error

Tags: ldap

I've finally got my LDAP server to work but now I'm having trouble constructing the DIT.
The LDIF for the DIT goes as follows:

```
dn: ou=uSocial,dc=ulyssis,dc=org
ou: uSocial
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: ou=Kringen,dc=uSocial,dc=ulyssis,dc=org
ou: Kringen
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

dn: ou=Personen,dc=uSocial,dc=ulyssis,dc=org
ou: Personen
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
```

The suffix is "dc=ulyssis,dc=org". When I try adding the ldif (be it using ldapadd or through the phpLDAPadmin) I get the following error:

> Could not add the object to the LDAP server.
>
> LDAP said:    No such object
>
> Error number: 0x20 (LDAP_NO_SUCH_OBJECT)
>
> Description:  That object does not exist.

What object is it that doesn't exist? The error is pretty vague..

When I remove all the suffixes from the ldif I get the following error:

> No DN or CONTAINER?

I do have a DN specified for every entry so I don't know what I'm doing wrong here either.

Can anyone please help me on doing this correctly? 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add the DSE dn first.

```
dn: dc=ulyssis,dc=org
objectClass: domain
dc: dc=ulyssis
```

This error indicates that the suffix is not configured correctly.

```
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
        additional info: no global superior knowledge
```

Comment: When I try to do this I get the following error: LDAP said: Server is unwilling to perform
Error number: 0x35 (LDAP_UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM)
Description: The LDAP server refused to perform the operation.

When I google this most comments talk about replication but I don't have this configured. Any ideas?

Comment: Depends on minor error text, but I suspect your suffix is not setup corretly. See edit.

Comment: @Foezjie are you binding with the rootDN set for the `dc=ulyssis,dc=org` database? Binding with the rootDN for another DB (like cn=config) will not work unless the rootDN is set the same for both databases.

Comment: @Patrick: I was indeed. But a restart of the server seemed to resolve my problems, the DIT is now a-ok.
Thanks anyways, you too @84104!